# Moving a list of files by matching them to a destination index

Tags: files, find, mv

Say I have two text files `src.txt` and `dest.txt`, where `src.txt` contains a list of filenames (some of which include spaces) in `/src/dir/` and `dest.txt` contains, in random order, a list of the complete file paths (again with spaces) where they belong. For example:

**src.txt:**

```
file 1.jpg
file_2.html
file 3.jpg
```

**dest.txt:**

```
/dest/dir 1/file 3.jpg
/dest/file4.txt
/dest/file 5.txt
/dest/dir 2/file 1.jpg
/dest/file_2.html
```

How can I perform this batch move operation from the shell? I have been working with a `while read` loop over the source file, and I am pretty sure I need to use the `mv` command, but I'm not sure if `grep` or `sed` are needed here. I keep running into `cannot stat...` and space-character resolution errors.

Comment: The destination list contains hundreds of extra lines, but all source files are represented once.

Comment: do the directories exist?

Comment: Yes. Folders are present.

Comment: so the delimiter is a newline? what if a filename listed in either file should contain a newline? is that ruled out here?

Comment: For this particular problem, the possibility of filenames containing newline characters was ruled out, yes. I suppose if a filepath exceeds a certain length that would need to be accounted for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
src=(${(f)"$(<src.txt)"})
for f (${(f)"$(<dest.txt)"})
(($src[(Ie)$f:t])) && mv /src/dir/$f:t $f
```

This reads each file in an array and then, for each element in the *"dest"* array, if the basename (`:t` is a `zsh` modifier which removes all leading pathname components) is also in the *"src"* array then it moves the file.
To perform a dry-run  replace `mv` with `printf '"%s" -> "%s"\n'`.

---

Now, you could also run (still in `zsh`):

```
for f (${(f)"$(grep -Ff src.txt dest.txt)"})
mv /src/dir/$f:t $f
```

which works fine as long as none of the file names in `src.txt` matches any of the directory names (or part of that name) in the list of paths in `dest.txt` (e.g. a file name `data1` in `src.txt` and a path like `/path/data1_dir/some_file` in `dest.txt` would give a false positive). To avoid that you could pass the file names to `grep` as patterns (i.e. using regex like `/filename$`) instead of `F`ixed strings so as to match only the last component of the paths in `dest.txt`. Though that requires escaping all special characters (if any) in file names in `src.txt`, e.g. this time with `bash` (`4`):

```
readarray -t files < <(sed 's|[[\.*^$/]|\\&|g;s|.*|/&$|' src.txt | grep -f- dest.txt)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do mv /src/dir/"${f##*/}" "$f"; done
```

Comment: The first set of commands worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If a newline is an acceptable delimiter then the following should be pretty robust in an POSIX shell:

```sh
IFS='
';set -f
for   f in $(cat <"$destfile")
do    [ -e "./${f##*/}" ] ||
      [ -h "./${f##*/}" ] &&
      mv   "./${f##*/}"  "$f"
done
```

There are two possible problems with that solution that I can imagine:

- The input file size is simply too large to split out in a single go like that.

  - On my system this doesn't really even bear seriously considering until input approaches many tens of thousands of lines.
- A filename in `$destfile` might exist in the current directory and yet should *not* be moved anyway.

  - Because this solution foregoes comparing the two input files entirely and only checks each last pathname component in `$destfile` for existence in the current directory, if any filenames might match unintentionally it should not be considered.

If only the first problem needs handling:

```sh
sed -ne"s|'|'"'\\&&|g' <"$destfile"    \
    -e "s|.*/\([^/].*\)|_mv './\1' '&'|p" | 
sh  -c '_mv(){ [ -e "$1" ]||[ -h "$1" ]&& mv "$@";};. /dev/fd/0'
```

If your `sh` is `dash` you might drop the `. /dev/fd/0` at the end and use:

```sh
sed ... | sh -cs '_mv(){ ...;}'
```

...because `dash` strangely handles both the command-line and stdin invocation options in concert and without complaint. That wouldn't be very portable, but `. /dev/fd/0` - while pretty portable - isn't strictly standards-compliant either.

If the second issue is a concern:

```sh
export  LC_ALL=C 
sed  -ne'\|/$|!s|.*/\(.*\)|\1/&|p' <"$destfile" |
sort -t/ -k1,1 - ./"$srcfile"  |  cut  -d/ -f2- |
sed  -e "\|/|!N;\|\n.*/|!d"    \
     -e "s|'|'"'\\&&|g'        \
     -e "s|\n|' '|;s|.*|mv './&'|" | sh
```

...that should handle it very nicely so long as all of the filenames in `./"$srcfile"` are properly and identically accounted for at the tail-end of some path in `"$destfile"`. `sort` will always float the shorter of two otherwise identical comparisons to the top, and so when only the first field matters, and the filename is prepended to the head of each pathname from `"$destfile"` then a merged `sort` operation of both files will output sequences like:

```
$srcfile:  no /
$destfile: match
$destfile: unique
$destfile: unique
...
$srcfile:  no /
$destfile: match
$destfile: unique
```

...and so you only need to concern yourself with pairs of lines beginning with one that doesn't match `/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read i; do echo cp \""$i"\" \"$(grep "/$i$" dst.txt)\"; done < src.txt
```

This will print what would have been done. Just get rid of the `echo` to actually copy the files.

Comment: The grep command should be looking for the pattern: `/$i$` to make sure `$i`matches only the last element of the paths in `dest.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

**A one-liner script generates a script which generates a script.**

In this example, we use a first invocation of `sed` on `src.txt` to generate a second `sed` script that will run on `dest.txt` to generate a shell script to copy the files.

Here's the one-liner:

```
$ sed -n "$(sed 's,\(..*\),/\\/\1$/ { s/^/cp "\1" "/; s/$/";/; p; },' src.txt)" dest.txt #| sh -x
```

and the output:

```
cp "file 3.jpg" "/dest/dir 1/file 3.jpg";
cp "file 1.jpg" "/dest/dir 2/file 1.jpg";
cp "file_2.html" "/dest/file_2.html";
```

Note the comment `#| sh` at the end of the command.  This way, you can try the command and see what it will do, and if it's good, uncomment the pipe to `sh` and really copy the files.

The inner sed command builds a sed script out of src.txt. The first line of the generated script looks like this:

```
/\/file 1.jpg$/ { s/^/cp file 1.jpg /; p; }
```

**This is how it works:**

Input:

```
    $ cat src.txt
    file 1.jpg
    file_2.html
    file 3.jpg

    $ cat dest.txt
    /dest/dir 1/file 3.jpg
    /dest/file4.txt
    /dest/file 5.txt
    /dest/dir 2/file 1.jpg
    /dest/file_2.html
```

First `sed` invocation.  This shows the generated script that will be interpreted by the second invocation of `sed`:

```
$ sed 's,\(..*\),/\\/\1$/ { s/^/cp "\1" "/; s/$/";/; p; },' src.txt
/\/file 1.jpg$/ { s/^/cp "file 1.jpg" "/; s/$/";/; p; }
/\/file_2.html$/ { s/^/cp "file_2.html" "/; s/$/";/; p; }
/\/file 3.jpg$/ { s/^/cp "file 3.jpg" "/; s/$/";/; p; }
```

Use shell command substition to use the output of the first `sed` command as a script on the command line passed to the second invocation of `sed`:

```
$ sed -n "$(sed 's,\(..*\),/\\/\1$/ { s/^/cp "\1" "/; s/$/";/; p; },' src.txt)" dest.txt
cp "file 3.jpg" "/dest/dir 1/file 3.jpg";
cp "file 1.jpg" "/dest/dir 2/file 1.jpg";
cp "file_2.html" "/dest/file_2.html";
```

Now, pipe the output of sed to the shell, with the xtrace option (`sh -x`).  I don't have any of the files, hence the errors:

```
$ sed -n "$(sed 's,\(..*\),/\\/\1$/ { s/^/cp "\1" "/; s/$/";/; p; },' src.txt)" dest.txt  | sh -x
+ cp file 3.jpg /dest/dir 1/file 3.jpg
cp: cannot stat ‘file 3.jpg’: No such file or directory
+ cp file 1.jpg /dest/dir 2/file 1.jpg
cp: cannot stat ‘file 1.jpg’: No such file or directory
+ cp file_2.html /dest/file_2.html
cp: cannot stat ‘file_2.html’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: you need to escape quotes, too. and backslashes. and `$` and basically every other expandable thing. else you could use `'` which would be a lot more sensible. you still need to escape quotes, though.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for pointing that out and I agree.  I usually use single quotes when possible.  In my experience, at the system level where the filenames are controlled, special chars have not been a problem with double quoted filenames.  I inferred from questioner's remarks about spaces that this was the case.  Practicality. Not defending this answer, just giving background.   My favorite answer to this question is blissini's http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/241129/139893 for simplicity and relevance to the question, though I think the quoting could be improved for readability.

Comment: but cant you see where that breaks too? there are things you can do which work most of the time, and there are similar things you can do which work all of it. its just good sense to shun the *most* things. in blissini's answer the the `read` breaks right off the bat with the spaces mentioned by the asker, backslashes are input escapes, the input is `read()` a single char at a time and so on. the `echo` then interprets backslash escapes again, leading dashes break `cp`, newlines are impossible, the command sub eats trailing newlines, dang. there's more. sorry. i feel like that stuff matters.